# The type javax.ServletException cannot be resolved with Worklight

Tags: eclipse, servlets, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Eclipse Luna and Worklight v6.2 with Java 7.
I am trying to run a project but I am getting the error

> the type javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from >required .class files

I have read many posts with similar issue but not with worklight. I am supposed to find servlet.jar and add it in the build path but I don´t know where to find it..

Thank you

Comment: Did you download Eclipse Luna Standard, or Eclipse Luna for Java EE developers.  You will need the latter.  See if you have WTP installed in eclipse.

Comment: I needed Luna for JAVA EE Developers, thank you :)

Comment: @MaryDefal or Zac Lozano, please write the above as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need Eclipse for JavaEE Developers.

Answer (score 1):

I am understand that you are working with native eclipse java project. It is not a maven project. If is:
Right click in your project -> build path -> configure build path.
Then select: add library and server runtime.
Worked for me. If don't for you, maybe your container is not well configurated in eclipse.